# Выводить исключения в stderr

Tags: c#, исключения, visual-studio-2015

Подскажите пожалуйста. Исключения (exceptions) в C# по умолчанию выводятся в stdout, мне нужно их выводить в stderr (чтобы потом обработать только поток ошибок). Возможно ли это как-то настроить в visual studio?

Comment: А почему нельзя обрабатывать исключения с помощью оператора `try-catch`?

Comment: Исключения никуда не выводятся. Они просто выбрасываются. А выводит информацию о них то окружение, в котором было запущено приложение. Если приложение консольное - будет вывод в консоль. Если приложение оконное - исключение будет или проглочено, или обработано отладчиком. Если это юнит-тест - вывод будет в тестовое окно. И т. п. В общем, уточните вопрос: какой тип приложения у вас и чего именно хотите добиться. Вероятно, вам нужно централизованно перехватывать необработанные ислючения?

Comment: У меня консольное приложение. Я запускаю его из Powershell, сохраняю вывод в log файл и хочу сохранять ошибки в отдельный файл, используя поток stderr. Я знаю, что в c# можно писать в stderr с помощью Console.Error.Write, но мне нужно, чтобы в этот поток попадали исключения (try-catch на все не навесишь). Это реально как-то сделать?

Comment: По умолчанию, необработанные ошибки пишутся в stderr (100%, только при этом идёт ещё и прерывание работы программы), но если вы насильно пишите `Console.WriteLine(err.ToString())` то конечно они попадут в stdout. Пишите их в stderr и всё. Так как ваш вопрос достаточно спорный - приведите конкретный пример того случая, где ваша ошибка пишется "нитуда".

Comment: Ну банально int a = 1 / 0;  Информация об ошибке содержится в stdout: "Error: Attempted to divide by zero."

Comment: Перехватывать все необработанные исключения можно с помощью события `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`.

Comment: Ну здесь я имела ввиду     int a = 0; int b = 1 / a;    Тогда будет ошибка выполнения. И у меня как раз     1.exe > 1.txt 2> 2.txt     записывает все в 1.txt, хотя error должен записывать в 2.txt

Comment: @МарияКарасева  CS0020 - ошибка компиляции, а не выполнения. Хорошо, поправлю на `int q=0; int a=1/q;` Исключение пошло в stderr, `1.exe >1.txt` файл 1.txt пустой, потому что в stdout ничего не пишется. Возможно вы сделали ошибку в Powershell. `Необработанное исключение: System.DivideByZeroException: Попытка деления на нуль`. Сообщение попало в 2.txt. Кстати Error не должно писать, должно писать Unhandled Exception. Вы что-то скрываете. Видимо есть какой-то обработчик который не отражён в вопросе.

Comment: @nick_n_a, проект не мой, поэтому возможно там действительно какие-то настройки, которые я не заметила. Сейчас проверю на новом проекте, если будет выводить в stderr, закрою тему и буду сама разбираться

Comment: Проверила, выводится в stderr, значит это в моем проекте какие-то особые настройки. В любом случае всем спасибо за помощь